# Updating DB Shema in Express JS with Mongoose library

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, mongoose

I have created a Mongo DB schema with Mongoose in Express.js and I am building the REST API. However when I try to update existing records the values that I do not update from the schema automatically become null. I understand why this happens just not sure exactly how it should be coded.

This is the route:

```js
router.patch("/:projectId", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const updatedProject = await Project.updateOne(
      { _id: req.params.projectId },
      {
        $set: {
          title: req.body.title,
          project_alias: req.body.project_alias,
          description: req.body.description
        }
      }
    );
    res.json(updatedProject);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
});
```

also here is the schema:

```js
const ProjectsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  project_alias: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  description: String,
  allowed_hours: Number,
  hours_recorded: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
  date_added: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});
```

My problem is that when I want to update just the title:

```
{
    "title" : "Title Updated33"
}
```

description and alias become null. Should I implement a check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use req.body for the update object like this:

```js
router.patch("/:projectId", async (req, res) => {

  try {
    const updatedProject = await Project.updateOne(
      { _id: req.params.projectId },
      req.body
    );
    res.json(updatedProject);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
});
```

Or even better, create a helper function like this so that we can exclude the fields in the body that doesn't exist in the model:

```js
const filterObj = (obj, ...allowedFields) => {
  const newObj = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(el => {
    if (allowedFields.includes(el)) newObj[el] = obj[el];
  });
  return newObj;
};

router.patch("/:projectId", async (req, res) => {
  const filteredBody = filterObj(
    req.body,
    "title",
    "project_alias",
    "description",
    "allowed_hours",
    "hours_recorded"
  );

  try {
    const updatedProject = await Project.updateOne(
      { _id: req.params.projectId },
      filteredBody
    );
    res.json(updatedProject);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
});
```